# How to set expire time of JWT Token in Laravel 5.1

Tags: django, api, laravel-5.1, jwt

I am making an authentication api with Django, JWT and Laravel 5.1. But i don't know how to set expire time for token and how to send it to API from Client (make by Laravel 5.1 too). Can anyone help me, i know it is a basic question but i was tried to google but don't have any answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JWT supports a number of reserved claims. One of these is "exp". You encode a claim with this name and a timestamp as the value:

```
$key = "example_key";
$token = array(
    "sample_key" => "sample_value",
    "exp" => 1356999524, // expiration timestamp
);


$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
```

Further reading: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519

Answer (score 2):

Change the value of

```
'ttl' => 60, //Defaults to 1 hour
```

in your project /config/jwt.php

This is in Laravel 5.2 & JWT 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, jwt tokens are used for ajax requests and api development. If you are using laravel blades for your client side, then you don't need to use jwt. Laravel has a built in services for CSRF tokens and authentication.

[laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection)

But you still need to use jwt, read this tutorial:

[Token-Based Authentication for AngularJS and Laravel Apps](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps)

Comment: this should be a comment!, btw my client made  by laravel 5.1 too so i don't know how to check it.

Comment: No i don't, i use JWT from my Laravel API send to the client. I am using the csrf token on my website now, but i don't know how to set expire time to the JWT on the API side